# Выбрать пользователей у которых нету твитов

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно показать пользователей у которых нету твитов ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд самым простым и быстрым решением для этой задачи будет использование конструкции `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
select 
  u.user_id  
from
  Users u
left outer join
  Tweets t on t.user_id = u.user_id
where
  t.user_id is null
```

Проверить можно [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c89d6/2).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` NOT IN( SELECT `user_id` FROM `tweets` );
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что это решение будет работать очень-очень медленно, особенно в случае большой таблицы tweets. Можно в подзапрос добавить слово `distinct`, оно улучшит дело, но всё равно запрос выглядит медленным.

Comment: если правильно выставленные индексы, то будет быстро. Ну хотя это не самый быстрый вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id 
                  FROM tweets t
                  WHERE t.`user_id` = u.`id`
)
```

`EXIST`- возвращает значение 1 (TRUE), если результат подзапроса содержит
хотя бы одну строку, и значение 0 (FALSE), если подзапрос выдает пустой результат

`NOT EXIST` - противоположен `EXIST`

[подробнее...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)